# Minimum symbols for wordpress search

Tags: javascript, php

It's my **searchform.php** file. How is it possible to set minimum symbols for search?

```
<div class="widget-search">
    <form action="<?php echo esc_url( get_home_url() ); ?>/" 
          class="searchform" id="searchform" method="get" role="search">
        <input type="text" value="<?php echo get_search_query(); ?>" 
               name="s" id="s"
               placeholder="<?php _e( 'Search...', 'pixar' ); ?>">
        <button type="submit"> <i class="fa fa-search"></i> </button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: what is minimum symbols? are youa sking min length of characters to be searched

Comment: @zod, I think he means length. He could just use strlen.

Comment: @zod yes, I mean min length of characters. For example, I have car dealer site. Each car has unique VIN number with 17 characters(always), But part of this characters may be the same. So, if visitor enters for example 3 characters, he will be able to see not only his car and it is not good. So, I want to have minimum length of characters to be searched - 17,

Comment: @Bug Thanks for your reply but what is it a strien and how to use it? I'm not good in php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get input text length and validate user in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825144/how-to-get-input-text-length-and-validate-user-in-javascript)